# trying to remove a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 2 subviews on the stage (a splash screen, and the main screen) once the splash screen finishes playing its audio it calls a function called `-(void)audioComplete` which is suppose to fade out the splash screen, revealing the main screen. I can't seem to get that working.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [self.window addSubview:splashController.view];
    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}


-(void)audioComplete{
    NSLog(@"REMOVE FROM STAGE");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:splashController.view];
    splashController.view.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [splashController release]; 
}
```

If I add `NSLog(@"%@",[splashController.view superview]);` in the `audioComplete` function I get `(null)`, but not when I add it to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple highly [recommends against using splash screens](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html). Instead, you should use an image called 'Default.png' in the root directory. This will get displayed while the application is launching and make it appear that your application is faster than it actually is. Apple could potentially reject your submission to the app store if you create your own loading screen.

Answer (score 1):

Could be one of two things:

1) Seems like your rootControllerView is being added on top of the splashControllerView.

Maybe your animation is happening but you can't see it as your rootControllerView is blocking it.

Try reversing your order of addSubview.

2) Don't release your splash view in the same method you're using for animation. Wait for the animation to finish before releasing your view. You can do this by:

```
-(void)audioComplete
{
    NSLog(@"REMOVE FROM STAGE");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidFinishSelector:@selector(releaseView)];
    splashController.view.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}

-(void)releaseView
{
    [splashController release];
}
```

Also, as a best practice for memory management, don't release splashControllerView directly.

What I do is release a view immediately after adding it as a subview (adding a subview increases it's retain count).

When I'm done with the subview, I simply call [subView removeFromSuperView] which reduces the retain count and makes it zero.

Simply put:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init]; //retain count = 1

[self.view addSubview:view]; //retain count = 2

[view release]; //retain count = 1

//do stuff with the view

[view removeFromSuperview]; //retain count = 0;
```

Comment: it could also be both 1 and 2 together

Comment: I bet its 1 and 2 - well analyzed, well formulated answer +1!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see your question, because in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you're adding your view and it's **really** there! So you will receive an answer every time you call `NSLog(@"%@",[splashController.view superview]);` but in `audioComplete` you release your subView and it's away... After this you can't get access to the superview, because - you're subView is released...

I would use this:

```
-(void)audioComplete{
    NSLog(@"REMOVE FROM STAGE");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:splashController.view];
    splashController.view.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [splashController.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

You'll get the same thing again, but you're subView is still there if you need something later.

Comment: ive tried that and i get warning: 'SplashPageView' may not respond to '-removeFromSuperview'

Comment: Oops. Should be [splashController.view removeFromSuperview];

Comment: ive tried taht too, but the spashController.view never animates and doesnt get removed, it just sits on stage

Comment: 2 things: 1) Is the viewController set as an instance in your class? 2) Why do you set the delegate to the view and not to your viewController?!

Answer (score 0):

For Fade in and Fade out images between splash and mainscreen. i suggest you could trying having two image in rootviewcontroller. made the fade in and fadeout animation between two UIIMageViews......

for fade in read out this sample tuts:

[http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/fade-transition-fade-images-in-and-out.html](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/fade-transition-fade-images-in-and-out.html)

during the animation, u can complete your audio streams